# How to fetch rows based on values in another column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table `Q`:

```
id      dept         Person        Rating
------------------------------------------
1       ece            p1           R1  
2       ece            p2           Null  
6       eee            P6           R1             
5       eee            p2           Null
6       Civil          P7           Null
7       Civil          P3           Null 
8       Civil          P8           R5
9       Mech           p7           R2
10      Mech           P3           Null
```

For `Q`, I need only rows whose person's Ratings are null and their respective persons in different team, ratings are same. Because P2 is in different teams ece and eee their respective person's ratings is same that is R1. "respective person's ratings" are the non-null-ratings of the other persons in the same dept?

Output for Q3

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
----------------------------------------
2       ece            p2           Null  
5       eee            p2           Null
```

It should not contain following rows, because P3 is in both Civil and Mech but person's ratings are different that is R5 and R2

```
id      dept         Person       Rating
----------------------------------------
7       Civil          P3           Null 
10      Mech           P3           Null
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you post the SQL please?

Comment: What is a "team"?  Your question is very hard to figure out.  Perhaps it could be rephrased.

Comment: What if there are two different rating in one departemnt/team?

Comment: I think editing the wording of your question can go a long way here. We definitely want to help you, but it is difficult for some of us to understand what you are asking with the way things are currently worded.

Comment: @Michal. I dont need rows having different rating in one department. Inorder to filter that I already have logic .  Selelct * from Ihavetable where  Dept in (select dept from  Ihavetable  Groiupby dept having count(distinct Rating)=1).   Now I have to filter rows for above condition.

Comment: @Jerry . In simple way I need only these two rows.                                           id      dept         Person       Rating
2       ece            p2           Null  
5       eee            p2           Null                  Because the non-null-ratings of the other persons in the same dept are same that is R1.    P2 is in ece and eee. the ratings of persons of ece and eee should be same, here in our case it is R1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my try and got as like your sample output

```
 with t1 as    
(
select * from 
(
select 1 as id, 'ece' as dept,  'p1' as Person ,'R1' as Rating
union all
select 2,'ece','p2', Null  
union all
select 6,'eee','P6','R1'
union all
select 5,'eee','p2',Null
union all
select 6,'Civil','P7', Null
union all
select 7,'Civil','P3', Null 
union all
select 8,'Civil','P8','R5'
union all
select 9,'Mech','p7','R2'
union all
select 10,'Mech','P3', Null


) t
) 
, t2 as
(
select dept,Person from t1 where rating is null
) ,
a as
(
select t3.* from t2 t3 join t2 t4 on t3.Person=t4.Person and t3.dept!=t4.dept
) ,

b as 
(
select * from t1 where t1.dept in (select dept from a) and t1.rating is not null
), c as
(
select r1.dept from b r1 join b r2 on r1.rating=r2.rating and r1.dept<>r2.dept
)
,d as
(
select * from t1 where t1.dept in (select dept from c) and t1.rating is null
) 
 select * from d
```

output

```
  id    dept    Person  Rating
  2     ece      p2      null
  5     eee      p2      null
```

Comment: id      dept         Person       Rating
2       ece            p2           Null  
5       eee            p2           Null        Thank you Zaynul but Output should contain only these two rows.   The condition is " P2 is in different Dept ece and eee right. The non-null ratings of ece and eee is same that is R1. "           Consider P3 whose dept is in civil and mech but the non null ratings of civil and mech are different that is R2 and R5 so I do not need these rows.       Please do help with the logic

Comment: @vishal yes the output is as like your sample , i edited i thought you need both btw if it works please accept answer

Comment: Zaynul. Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there any other way. I have 11,000 records its taking 3 Minutes to fetch the records

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
declare @tab table (id int, dept varchar(100), Person varchar(10), Rating varchar(10))
insert into @tab select 1,'ece', 'p1','R1'
insert into @tab select 2,'ece', 'p2',Null
insert into @tab select 6,'eee', 'P6','R1'
insert into @tab select 5,'eee', 'p2',Null
insert into @tab select 6,'Civil', 'P7',Null
insert into @tab select 7,'Civil', 'P3',Null 
insert into @tab select 8,'Civil', 'P8','R5'
insert into @tab select 9,'Mech ', 'p7','R2'
insert into @tab select 10,'Mech ', 'P3',Null

select id, dept, Person,Rating from
@tab t where dept in
(
    select dept from
    @tab t
    where rating in (
        select Rating from @tab
        where Rating is not null    
        group by Rating
        having count(distinct dept) > 1
))
and t.Rating is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with team1 as    
(
select * from 
(
select 1 as id, 'ece' as dept,  'p1' as Person ,'R1' as Rating
union all
select 2,'ece','p2', Null  
union all
select 6,'eee','P6','R1'
union all
select 5,'eee','p2',Null
union all
select 6,'Civil','P7', Null
union all
select 7,'Civil','P3', Null 
union all
select 8,'Civil','P8','R5'
union all
select 9,'Mech','p7','R2'
union all
select 10,'Mech','P3', Null


) t
) ,
UniqueRatingCTE as (
 SELECT *
FROM team1
WHERE   dept IN (
  SELECT  dept  
  FROM team1 
  GROUP BY dept
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Rating) =1 
  )) ,


    calculation AS (
        SELECT t1.Person
        FROM UniqueRatingCTE t1
            INNER JOIN UniqueRatingCTE t2 ON t1.dept = t2.dept
        WHERE t1.Rating  IS NULL
        GROUP BY t1.Person
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Rating) = 1
           --AND COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Person) >= 2
    )
SELECT *
FROM UniqueRatingCTE
WHERE Rating IS NULL
  AND Person IN (SELECT Person FROM calculation) order by Person;
```

---

This one is working somehow. I got it from Kais.